# Split datetime of api response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting info from an API, and what I want to do is get the response of date time. This is part of my code:

```
function perDetail(){
    $http.get('/api/values')
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.details = data.data.Response;
});
}
```

Part of what i get is:

```
"Date":"2018-07-16T18:00:00"
```

And what I wanna do is get the hour:

```
18:00
```

Someone can guide me, please? I know there's a split and splice method, but I can't get the value. Maybe sounds too easy but right now, I'm stuck with this.

I'm using AngularJs and Javascript.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Is this the format the date will always have?

Comment: @lealceldeiro yes, always the same format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

```
var date = "2018-07-16T18:00:00";
var time = date.split("T")[1]; // time is "18:00:00"
var justHour = time.slice(0, 5); //from index 0 to index 5 (first 5 characters)
return justHour; //"18:00"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have only `HH:MM` by converting `String` date to `Date` and get required fields. Below are several ways.

```js
var date = "2018-07-16T18:00:00";

var mydate = new Date(date);
console.log(mydate.getHours());
console.log(mydate.getMinutes());
console.log(mydate.toTimeString());
console.log(mydate.toTimeString().split(" ")[0]);
console.log(mydate.getHours(),":",mydate.getMinutes());
console.log(mydate.toTimeString().replace(/.*(\d{2}:\d{2})(:\d{2}).*/, "$1"));
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, "Date" is a key in the response object you are getting from your API call, right? And you just want to get the hours:minutes part in the corresponding value?

If that's correct, I think slicing the value in the right places would do the job:

```
data["Date"].slice(-8, -3)
```

Comment: But @lealceldeiro's question is super valid: It only works if the format of the returned object will always be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using getHours(), getMinutes(), getSeconds() functions? You can combine results and get time.

```
var d = new Date("July 21, 1983 01:15:00");
var h = d.getHours();
var m = d.getMinutes();
var s = d.getSeconds();
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp